# Auto set Active Directory attributes upon new User creation

Tags: active-directory, openldap, posix

I have successfully created an OpenLDAP (CentOS 6.2) to Active Directory (Windows Server 2008 R2) connection. I can login to my CentOS using an AD user.

Problem is, the AD user has to have these attributes:

- objectClass = posixAccount
- objectClass = posixGroup
- homeDirectory =/home/* username *

If I set these attributes manually using ldapmodify, upon logging into CentOS, the directory will be created.

So, how can I automatically set these attributes for the User upon creation? eg: when I right click on a user under Server Manager on Windows 2008, and go to the Profile tab, under Local Path it should be : /home/ * username */ listed instead of it being blank by default.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: My solution is to create a script that sets those attributes.  Create user, run script.  There's even a way to integrate the process so the same script that creates the user also populates the attributes you want, but for some reason I've been too lazy to get to it.  I am kind of curious to see if there's a better way, though.

Comment: Hi, I've been looking at that alternative as well. Problem is also that right now it requires that the Unix Attribute tab to be filled in, ie: UID which is auto generated. I wrote an LDIF file but was wondering if there is a way to insert variables into the file, such that for homeDirectory it would show /home/* username * of that user created.